# HTTP 400 Bad request while requesting access-token for LinkedIn API call

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I have been trying to get an access-key for making LinkedIn API calls. I've used the PHP sample code given on the forum, and have run it once for getting Authorisation-Code. After that I've tried using this code to generate the Access-Key, however, when I make the POST(or even the GET) request, I get a HTTP 400 bad-request, with this message:

failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

Can someone please tell me a fix for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using? Or at least link to the original?

Comment: You may see the PHP code that I used [here](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/code-samples) @PeterR.Bloomfield